# How to estimate runway length for airport master planning?

Tags: runways, airport-design

I use the manufacturer aiport planning manuals. But they are incomplete (unless for Boeing). Airbus and Embraer for example, only present range X weight charts for MTOW.
Is there a free (or affordable) software or good charts for this estimation?
I'm interested in airport planning.

Comment: Not sure what you are after, Airbus and Embraer do include take-off field length charts in their airport manuals.

Answer (score 3):

The [airport planning manuals](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/support-services/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics.html) from Airbus do include take-off field length charts for various weights, temperature and airport elevation.

Those of Embraer contain similar charts.